# Doctrine Select with Join -- Silex

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, silex

I am trying to make a SELECT within a Doctrine join, and am getting `Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.`

I have the following Doctrine query, which correctly returns Campaign entities after joining with brand/sponsor table and publisher table:

```
$qb = $this->em
        ->getRepository('App\Entities\Campaign')
        ->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->join('c.brand', 's')
        ->where('s.is_curated = 1')
        ->join('c.publisher', 'p')
        ->orWhere('p.is_curated = 1');
```

However, I want to select and return all distinct publisher entities, not the campaign entities.

So I try adding this line:

```
->select('c.publisher')
```

Which causes `Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.`

Why is this, and how do I select all distinct Publisher entities from the resulting Campaign entities?

Comment: You could add an `->addSelect('p')` as you already have a `->select('c')` from the createQueryBuilder method. But I'd suggest making a new query from the correct repository. If you want to fetch publishers then use that repo, not some other one.

Comment: The problem is that the Publisher repository doesn't have a pointer to Campaigns or Brands. I want to return all distinct Publishers who is_curated or have been involved in a Campaign with an is_curated Brand.

Comment: Can't you just add an association from publisher to campaign then? you already have the association the other way around